# Execute SQL Task with multiple stored procedures with input and out parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sp-executesql

I have an "Execute SQL Task" with ONE stored procedure which needs to be called multiple times.

This stored procedure takes one input value and returns one output value.

So my code is like :

```
EXEC test.sp_workdone ?,'TableName'  
EXEC test.sp_workdone ?,'TableName1'  
EXEC test.sp_workdone ?,'TableName2'
```

Where table name is different and "?" is same parameter that I need to pass. Also output is also one parameter which will be same for every result.

What I want to achieve here is to insert the value into a table and input value and out value which will be same one at given execution.

For example, `Audit_Table`: 1st execution

```
1, Table, X  
1, Table2,X  
1, Table3,X
```

`Audit_Table`: 2nd execution

```
2, Table, X1  
2, Table2,X1  
2, Table3,X1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution !

I had to use one more Execute SQL Task which will generate Table list for which we supposed to use SP.
then use that list using For East Loop container and use that list into that SP using Execute SQL Task. :)